# Give access to single pod in kubernetes using RBAC

Tags: kubernetes, devops, rbac

I want to access only one pod remotely using kubectl so followed instructions mentiond [here](https://jeremievallee.com/2018/05/28/kubernetes-rbac-namespace-user.html).

In order to do so, I created a `access.yml` file in kubernetes:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: devops-user
  namespace: default

---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: devops-user-limited-access
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]

---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: devops-user-view
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: devops-user
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: devops-user-limited-access
```

In my remote laptop I created a file in `~/.kube/config` like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
preferences: {}

# Define the cluster
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <my-ca.crt>
    # You'll need the API endpoint of your Cluster here:
    server: https://<server-ip>:6443
  name: kubernetes

# Define the user
users:
- name: devops-user
  user:
    as-user-extra: {}
    client-key-data: <my-ca.crt>
    token: <token-created-by-k8s>

# Define the context: linking a user to a cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    namespace: default
    user: devops-user
  name: default

# Define current context
current-context: default
```

Now I have "full access" to "all pods" but this is not what I want. I just want to have:

> I want "full access" to only "one pod".

Answer (score 4):

just add this to your role file

```
resourceNames: ["POD_NAME"]
```

so your role yaml file should be like this

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: devops-user-limited-access
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["pods", "pods/log"]
  resourceNames: ["POD_NAME"] <-------------------------------here
  verbs: ["get", "list"]
```

Comment: Now `kubectl get pod` throws this error:

Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:devops-user" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"

Comment: @VahidF are your sure you have that pod and role in default namespace?

Comment: @VahidF check by using ```kubectl auth can-i get pods -n default --as devops-user``` check what the answer you get . and make sure the pod that you are trying to get should be in same namespace

Comment: @VahidF can you do ```kubectl describe role devops-user-limited-access ```

Comment: No. I am trying to find a way to show you the output.

Comment: Output tells me I have `*` access to `*` , `*.apps` and `*.extensions` on `my-pod` resource name.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach to solve this. You can label the pods with specific key-value and then use [OPA](https://www.openpolicyagent.org) policy engine and write policy using [rego](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/) policy language which allows specific service account to do certain operation such as read, write etc on pod with that specific label.

In OPA a validating webhook will either allow or deny the request based on the policy you define.

As suggested in other answers the RBAC offered by kubernetes will not work if your pods are created by a deployment because pod names are dynamically generated in that case. Using OPA you can have more finegrain control than Kubernetes RBAC.